# Switching multiple user at once

Tags: bash

I have a need in my bash script where user have to execute one script on multiple hosts.
Lets say `user1 , user2, & user3`.
User1 have an access to switch to user2 but not user3 and the script has to be execute via user3.
To execute in one host - its possible as below- lets I am user1 and will execute below commands.

```
sudo -i -u user2
sudo -u user3 script <hostname>
```

But unable to execute on multiple hosts via for loop as below

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -i -u user2;
for i in `cat /tmp/hostlist`;do
  echo $i
  sudo -u user3 script.sh $i
  echo "----------------"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute second sudo as a argument to first sudo. It will looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo -i -u user2 /bin/bash <<EOF
#commands here will be executed as user=user2
while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do 
  echo "$i"
  sudo -u user3 script.sh "$i"
  echo "----------------"
done </tmp/hostlist
EOF
```

Testing:

```
$ echo 111 >/tmp/hostlist
$ echo 222 >>/tmp/hostlist
$ echo 333 >>/tmp/hostlist
$ ./loophosts 
111
----------------
222
----------------
333
----------------
```

Comment: `for i in $(cat /tmp/hostlist)` will fail if there are lines with IFS characters in the file, to loop over a file line by line one should rather use `while IFS='' read -r l || [[ -n "$l" ]]; do (something with $l); done </tmp/hostlist`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/6164712.

Comment: The error about you don't have EOF, put it in place and error will gone

Comment: Same error? Do you have "EOL" at end of heredoc?

Comment: Yes I placed at end EOF. The error gone. But gives the single line as output 

----------------

Comment: You can debug bash script if put `set -x` as second line of script, then it will show every command it run. I guess something wrong with /tmp/hostlist

Comment: Every host on new line?

Comment: Try your original "for" loop, but inside my script, replacing while-done section

Comment: The idea about sudo and heredoc("<<EOF..EOF") is correct, but something wrong with a loop, and I can't guess what. Dont forget to quote: "$i"

Comment: I have do a test with script, check it. All working fine.

Comment: I am sure issue is with line - sudo -i -u user2 /bin/bash  << EOF